# Using a number as a switch parameter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am trying to build a cool "PowerShell command"  (a script containing a global function that I could later use from the shell as a command) and I have a problem.

I am using parameters with `param()` and there is an option to use a switch parameter (one that does not get subsequent information but just used for an option later on - such as the `-l` at the Linux command `ls`).

The thing is that it works fine when the parameter name is a letter, but not with a number. It's strange since numbers could be defined as variables (`$4`).

What do I need to do?

It suppose to be like `ping -6`.

Ideas?

Comment: You don't need to do anything - because it can't be done. The [PowerShell Language Specification §2.3.4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389) defines parameter names as starting with a *letter*

Comment: Kinda funny that this constraint still exists when they allow Unicode letters as the first character ...

Comment: What is the reason you need a number as the name for a variable? If you would like to write a function like ping -6, in PowerShell would make a function like `Ping {param ([ValidateSet(4,6)][int]$IPVersion) ...}` and you still can use this parameter as a boolean later on.

Comment: It is a function that connects netapp with powershell, by default to the clustered on tap but I wanted a "-7" switch to connect to a 7-mode netapp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible, as [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975695/using-a-number-as-a-switch-parameter-in-powershell#comment67230666_39975695) pointed out in the comments.

From §2.3.4 of the [language specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389):

> ### 2.3.4 Parameters
>
> **Syntax:**
>
> ```
> command-parameter:
>     dash   first-parameter-char   parameter-chars   colonopt
> first-parameter-char:
>     A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, or Lo
>     _   (The underscore character U+005F)
>     ?
> …
> ```

The closest you get is something like this:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [Switch]$_7
)
```

However, for your scenario something like this would be far more readable anyway:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [ValidateSet(3,5,7)]
  [int]$Mode = 7
)
```